# why i am not getting desired output?

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter a two numbers :");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    char x;
    scanf("%s",&x);
    switch(x)
    {
        
        case '+' :
            printf("a+b=%d",a+b);
            break;
        case '-' :
            printf("a-b=%d",a-b);
            break;
        default:
            printf("try again");
            break;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

suppose i take two input 4 and 5 and then press + sign then i get output like a+b=4 why i am not get output a+b=9 ?. please help me i am very new in c programming.

Comment: `%s` stores a string not a single char. A string is a NUL terminated char sequence. Need two chars to store a one letter string. What you have results in a buffer overflow and hence undefined behaviour.

Comment: Post exact input use.  Was it `"45+"` or `"4 5 +\n"` or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char x;
scanf("%s",&x);
```

This is scanning a *string,* not a character. That means it will write the `+` to `x` and the `\0` string terminator to some other piece of memory, which looks to be one of your variables in this case. For *example,* let's say your variables are laid out as follows:

```
Address m    : x
        m + 1: b with least significant byte first
        m + 5: a with least significant byte first
```

When you scan `a` and `b`, the situation is as follows:

```
Address m    : x = ?
        m + 1: b = 5, 0, 0, 0
        m + 5: a = 4, 0, 0, 0
```

Then, scanning the *string* `+`, the situation changes to:

```
Address m    : x = '+'
        m + 1: b = 0, 0, 0, 0
        m + 5: a = 4, 0, 0, 0
```

You'll see there that the `\0` string terminator has overwritten the first byte of `b`, making the resultant value zero, the exact same effect you seem to have.

Writing beyond the end of an memory of an object  is undefined behaviour.

The *easiest* fix is probably just to scan `"%c"` or `" %c"` (the latter will skip any white space before reading the character) rather than `"%s"`, although more robust code would use a better user input function like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-do-i-read-a-string-entered-by-the-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

That's ***vital*** if you're considering scanning strings with a unbounded `"%s"` (with no length limits) since there's *no* way to protect from buffer overflow in that case.

If you had entered something larger like `MyHovercraftIsFullOfEels`, you would most likely have corrupted stack control information rather than just a small part of one local variables, and this would probably have lead to your code crashing spectacularly (or worse).

As an aside, it's also a good idea to get into the habit of checking the return value of functions that return useful information, such as `scanf()`. It returns the number of items successfully scanned, which you can verify before making assumptions that prove potentially damaging, something like:

```
if (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Well, that didn't work at all\n");
    exit(1);
}

// We now have two integers so carry on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To input a character you need to use the conversion specifier `c` instead of `s`. The conversion specifier `s` is designed to input a string.

So write

```
char x = '\0';
scanf(" %c",&x);
      ^^^
```

Pay attention to the blank before the character `%`. It allows to skip white space characters.